# Apache with HTTP/2 and per-directory upload_max_filesize

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, php.ini, http2

I just upgraded my apache2 server on Debian 9.13 Stretch to start using HTTP/2. [As far as I'm concerned](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-enable-http-2-in-apache/), that requires switching from mod_php to PHP-FPM.

The problem is that PHP-FPM does not obey certain apache directives from .htaccess. For instance, I've been using `php_value upload_max_filesize 900M` in the an .htaccess file at the upload directory, to increase the filesize and other related parameters like `max_execution_time` and `post_max_size` in a finer grain than using the global php.ini file.

These are some of the alternatives I already tried:

1. Using PHP `ini_set()` method: `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` are used before my script is started.
2. Using .user.ini override files: less than ideal, since it would require restricting the upload of .ini files in every single place that allows to upload stuff (I can use a `<Files>` filter to disable read access, but not uploading).
3. Renaming the .user.ini file to `SOME_SCRAMBLED_TEST.ini` and adding a Require all denied to such files: dangerous, since a single php `scandir` at the wrong place may reveal my secured-by-obscurity config.
4. Changing it in the php.ini script: would take this as the last option; I prefer to have a rather high upload size than allowing users to upload a .user.ini file that screw my server.

Is there any other alternative to use HTTP/2 and have a secure server that allows uploads?

Comment: use the apache config directly to limit it?

Comment: Hi @djdomi, thanks for your answer! Could you please ellaborate? Do you mean setting it up in the VirtualHost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of work, I managed to have this running.

First, forbid the `.user.ini` dangerous default of reading it on every single directory:

```
# an empty user_ini filename disables its usage.
user_ini.filename =
```

Then, enable it only for the desired directory at the `apache2.conf` file located in `/etc/apache2` (and disable reading those). We can do this by using `SetEnv` with a Directory filter:

```
<Directory /path/to/upload/directory>
        SetEnv PHP_VALUE "user_ini.filename = .user.ini"
        <Files ".user.ini">
                Require all denied
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

Then, at the `/path/to/upload/directory`, create a `.user.ini` file with your required configuration:

```
post_max_size = 2048M
upload_max_filesize = 2048M
max_execution_time = 10
max_input_time = 10
```

This way you can have a per-directory `.user.ini` without enabling it for the whole server.

Comment: He was faster as me :)

Comment: @djdomi work pressure :) thanks for the hint!